# Fix indention in Visual Studio when pasting from eBook

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Every time I paste code from an Adobe reader eBook into Visual Studio it ends up looking like the image below. The only way I know to fix it is to go on each and every line and manually tab/backspace it all back in order. Source formatting does nothing (Edit>Advanced>Format Document)

Anyone know how to fix the indention in this scenario?

Thanks

I guess I cant post images yet.. image below

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/416645/ugly.jpg

Comment: @McAden and Zachary, those settings still do not seem to completely fix certain lines, take a look at another example here:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/416645/ex2.jpg

It seems to only format and work on code that has a matching closing tag. If the tag closes itself it just ignores it.

Comment: Please disregard my second update. The link McAden gave, if you use the exact settings as those pictured in the post, it does format the code very nicely.

Comment: I've tried he settings in the linked post which you accepted as an answer, but no luck. Code pasted from PDF just doesn't format, even after changing to my pet hate setting: "insert spaces"!

Comment: oops. My code was missing a closing }. You can't expect formatting to work when it's not valid. Duh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](https://web.archive.org/web/20210116172353/http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/09/29/cleaning-up-xaml-code-and-improving-parsing-time-with-blend.aspx#lbu_note2) explains the editor settings for XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Cntrl-K-D is the shortcut to format the source code, I use it all the time to clean up back copy & paste.